# 2 actions linked to the same onClick function

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown which closes when you click on it. 
But, the dropdown contains one a link which allows to download a file. 
If I add to my dropdown :

```
$('.dropdown').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It will prevent it to be closed when you click on it but it will also prevent the download from happening. 
Is there a better way to handle the event to prevent the dropdown from being closed, but still allowing the a links to work ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe `e.stopPropagation()`? Verify the `a` element to not have the `.dropdown` class

Comment: Please make a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `e.preventDefault()`

The latter prevents the default action from taking place. So it prevents the click on the link too.

But the former only...

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

It will still let your link to be clicked - but cuts the propagation down from the click event of the drop down.